# CKEditor doesn't save data

Tags: django, django-forms, ckeditor, htmx

I'm using CKEditor for a form. In the admin it works fine, but when using it in the ModelForm of a CreateView the editor doesn't save data. As in the official docs, with this code:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'fee']
```

And this html:

```
<div>
    <form hx-post="{{ request.path }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="modal-content">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1>Create new event</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{form.media}}
            {{form.as_p}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It won't let me submit the form as it will keep saying that the description field is required. Trying to add the CKEditor widget field in the **init** method, with this code:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'type', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'fee']  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_date'].widget = forms.SelectDateWidget()
        self.fields['end_date'].widget = forms.SelectDateWidget()
        self.fields['description'].widget = CKEditorWidget()
```

The form will be sent, and the instance created. However, the 'description' field will be empty even if I enter some content. This is my view:

```
class CreateEvent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = 'events/events_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('events:index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        event_obj = form.save(commit=True)
        image = self.request.FILES.get('image')
        if image:
            EventImage.objects.create(title=event_obj.title, image=image, event=event_obj)
        return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Trigger' : 'eventsListChanged'})
```

How should I make sure the data is being saved from the CKeditor?

Answer (score 0):

In models.py

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
```

In your model

```
description = RichTextField()
```

You don't need to do anything in the forms.py except putting it in the fields list

Comment: I need to specify the widget asociated to that field, if not it will not render. I think it has to do with HTMX and its way to handle post requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hx-vals` to pass description value manually.
Something like this should work:

```
hx-vals="js:{description: CKEDITOR.instances.id_description.getData()}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id_description') when I try to send the form. I'm adding the hx-vals atribute just after hx-post in the send button.

Comment: Can you update the original post with the exact html and form class that you have currently (including hx-vals)? The attribute has to be added to the "form" tag and this assumes you have ckeditor field called "description". Also if you can add which ver of htmx and ckeditor do you use. Thanks.